# Example of non-integral-domain such that all localizations at primes are integral domains.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, localization

I have to find a ring $A$ that is not an integral domain, but such that $A_p$ is an integral domain for every prime ideal $p\subset A$.

Set $A:=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$. Its only (prime) ideals are $p:=3\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ and $q:=2\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$; neither $p$ nor $q$ contain other ideals, so $A_p$ and $A_q$ are fields. Does this example work? It seems ok but I wouldn't be surprised if I made some mistake. (From exercise 3.5 of Atiyah-Macdonald)

Comment: Yes, it works. But how you concluded that the localizations are fields? From what you say they are local rings of dimension zero and nothing more.. (There are some obvious reasons for they are fields, but I can't see anyone in your question.)

Comment: Thanks for your correction, but now I'm a bit confused. The ideals of $A_p$ are in bijection with the ideals of $A$ contained in $p$, and we have that $(0)\subsetneq p$ are contained in $p$. So they survive in $A_p$ and we have $(0)\subsetneq pA_p$, since the bijection preserves inclusion. However if $A_p$ is a field I should prove that $pA_p=0$; where am I wrong?

Comment: @Carlos Careful: the *prime* ideals of $A_p$ are in bijection with the *prime* ideals of $A$ contained in $p$. In your case $(0)$ is not prime, so $p$ is the only prime ideal contained in $p$, and therefore $A_p$ has only one prime ideal. It does not follow from this that $A_p$ is a field, since the unique prime ideal of $A_p$ may not be the zero ideal.

Comment: For example, the localization of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ at $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field.

Answer (score 1):

*To get this out of unanswered-limbo*

---

It turns out that any direct product of more than one field will work.

There are many ways to see it but here's one I like: such rings are von Neumann regular, meaning for every element $a$ there's another element $b$ such that $a=aba$ (you can check this.)

Now, one key observation is that the localization of a von Neumann regular ring is again von Neumann regular.  (You can show the fractions satisfy that identity easily.)

Finally, a (commutative) local von Neumann regular ring is a field.  (From $aba=a$ we can see that $ab$ is an idempotent. In a local ring the idempotents are just $0$ and $1$ so either $ab=1$ and $a$ is a unit, or else $ab=0$ and $aba=a=0$.)

So: all the localizations of such a ring are integral domains (fields even.)